# Can I save a PDO connection to $GLOBALS and use it later to ensure that connection is created once?

Tags: php, pdo

I just want to make sure that PDO connection is created once in order to give some optimization to the script.

The code below can become much more pretty and maintainable but here I just want to keep it as simple as possible. (i.e. using classes and constructors)

Does this code ensure that PDO connection is created once? In another words a called method should be able to retrieve the connection which is already created in index.php and use it.

May it be more optimized (increasing performance)?

***Update:
I'm not talking about persistent connection.***

**index.php**

```
require 'file.php';
$GLOBALS['db_connection'] = new PDO("sqlite:db.sqlite");
if(request == 'create_user')
  user::create_user();
// ...
else
  exit();
```

**file.php**

```
class user{
  public static function create_user(){
    $conn = $GLOBALS['db_connection']; // should not attempt to reconnect because a PDO connection is already made in index.php
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 ...");
    // ...
    functions::do_sth(); // again should not attempt to reconnect because a PDO connection is already made in index.php
    // ...
    exit();
  }
}

class functions{
  public static function do_sth(){
    $conn = $GLOBALS['db_connection']; // should not attempt to reconnect because a PDO connection is already made in index.php
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes technically you can but using global variables is frowned upon in general. Be aware that the "simplicity" of the current solution comes at the cost of the future maintainability and flexibility

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks. How may I simply improve it?

Comment: Create a database interface class with the connection as a static class member (if you're **sure** you never want more than 1 connection) - pass that object into your `User` class constructor (though there should probably be another layer of abstraction there; a `User -> Database` interfacing class).

Comment: Well as long as your OOP is rather a cargo cult one (no offense but classes with static methods is no real OOP but rather namespaced functions) any approach would do, even globals. If you want your OOP to be proper, make your methods non-static, [pass the database connection in the constructor, assign it to a class variable and use it in the methods](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#dependency_injection).

Comment: @YourCommonSense My OOP is not that bad ;) I just used such dumb code in order to make the question more understandable.

Comment: I see. Then I would strongly recommend the way I offered. And then, as soon as you will have your classes created on the fly (just like all PHP frameworks do), you'd have to use a Dependency injection Container that will take care of providing the connection instance for the classes.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The provided link was great. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. It is actually to my site, you may find many interesting information specifically related to PDO, however it is mostly uses mysql flavor (but for the most part there is no difference with sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to your code is to use the Singleton pattern.

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single" instance. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

Example:

```
class Connection {
   private static $instance;
   public static function make($config){
    try {
        if(self::$instance === NULL) {

            self::$instance = 
                new \PDO ("mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";
                dbname=" . $config['name'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['options']
                );

        }

        return self::$instance;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        die("Database connection error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
  }
}

// use 
$dbConnection = Connection::make($config['database']);
```

Comment: Wow! That's it. So if I opt out (skip) code maintainability and choosing a right design pattern (I should really avoid this), Does your code and mine behave same?

Comment: @sam Singleton is rather an antipattern and is frowned upon as much as globals. So don't be that excited

Comment: Not to mention that PDO specific part here is a distinct display of bad practices

Comment: @YourCommonSense Singleton is mostly frowned upon because it makes testing harder becuse it is harder to replicate. This should not be a big problem for database connection.

Comment: @SamTheExhausted This code should behave like your code

Comment: Singleton is frowned upon because it makes your code tightly coupled, with testing issue being just one of consequences. And speaking of testing, Singleton *is* the issue as many use a different database connection for tests

Comment: @YourCommonSense But Singleton is much better than using $GLOBALS ;)